# Why is no data being displayed

Tags: php, xml, sorting

Hi guys this is annoying me now

here is my code & the link to xml file is included

```
   <?php
function betlist($viewbets){
$eid=$viewbets;
$events=(object)array(
    'horses'    =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml',
        'query' =>  '//event/bettype[ number( @bettypeid )="'.$eid.'" ]'
    ),
    'football'  =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/football-bonus.xml',
        'query' =>  '//event/bettype'
    ),
    'goals'     =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/goals-galore.xml',
        'query' =>  '//event[ number( @eventid )="'.$eid.'" ]/bettype/bet'
    )
);

/* the last one will be used */
$obj=$events->horses;
$obj=$events->football;
$obj=$events->goals;


/* create the DOM object & load the xml */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $obj->url );

$root=$dom->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0);

/* Create a new XPath object */
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* Search the DOM for nodes with particular attribute - bettypeid - use number function from XSLT to test */
$oCol=$xp->query( $obj->query );

/* If the query was successful there should be a nodelist object to work with */
if( $oCol ){

   // echo "<div id='bfresults'>";

    foreach( $oCol as $node ) {
        echo '<div class="unit-100 centered" style="margin-left:0px; text-align:left;">'.$node->parentNode->getAttribute('name').'</div>';

        foreach( $node->childNodes as $bet ){
            echo "<div class=\"unit-30\">{$bet->getAttribute('name')}</div><div class=\"unit-30\">".$bet->getAttribute('id')."<div class=\"unit-30\">".$bet->getAttribute('price')."</div>";
        }
    }
    echo "</div>";

} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}
$dom = $xp = $col = null;
}

?>
```

Now all I want is it to display the 
current event name in a H1 tag
then it listing each bettype element with each bet element name and price that it contains

please help guys im so nearly there but really feel like crying over this lol

Comment: do you mean `@eventid`

Comment: The path in the xpath expression is wrong - aside from `evenitid` you are missing the `bettype` from the path

Comment: its just annoying me now, it should have been a simple change over from another feed as they are formatted the same but for some stupid reason i cant even see what im doing worng, have been looking at code for way too many hours now and am going a bit blind to it

Comment: found my problem, .. sorry really blind today

Comment: 1 question though how do I get it to display the bettype name only once instead of repeating with each record displayed

Comment: off the top of my head, use an array to hold the various elements as you iterate through the XML Dom - check if an item is not in the array as you go and then, at the end, implode the array and echo it out to screen

Comment: also ive commented out the bfresults div because i have a div open just before the function call

Comment: In that case ( re above statement ) I would remove the closing `div` tag from within the function and use aclosing `div` tag in the html/php page after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

For the `XPath` expression, try:

```
$oCol=$xp->query( '//event[ number( @eventid )="'.$eid.'" ]/bettype/bet' );

or perhaps

$oCol=$xp->query( '//event[ number( @eventid )="'.$eid.'" ]/bettype' );
```

Again, continuing from previous example:

```
$eid=5078689.20;/* Tottenham v Leicester */

$events=(object)array(
    'horses'    =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/Horse-Racing-Daily.xml',
        'query' =>  '//event/bettype[ number( @bettypeid )="'.$eid.'" ]'
    ),
    'football'  =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/football-bonus.xml',
        'query' =>  '//event/bettype'
    ),
    'goals'     =>  (object)array(
        'url'   =>  'http://xml.betfred.com/goals-galore.xml',
        /*'query'   =>  '//event[ number( @eventid )="'.$eid.'" ]/bettype/bet',*/
        'query' =>  '//event[ number( @eventid )="'.$eid.'" ]/bettype'
    )
);

/* the last one will be used */
$obj=$events->horses;
$obj=$events->football;
$obj=$events->goals;


/* create the DOM object & load the xml */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $obj->url );

$root=$dom->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0);

/* Create a new XPath object */
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* Search the DOM for nodes with particular attribute - bettypeid - use number function from XSLT to test */
$oCol=$xp->query( $obj->query );

/* If the query was successful there should be a nodelist object to work with */
if( $oCol ){

    echo "<div id='bfresults'>";

    foreach( $oCol as $node ) {
        echo '
            <section>
                <h1>'.$node->parentNode->getAttribute('name').' - <span>[ '.$node->getAttribute('name').' ]</span></h1>
                <h2>'.date( 'D, j F, Y H:i:s', strtotime( $node->getAttribute('bet-start-date').' '.$node->parentNode->getAttribute('time') ) ).'</h2>';

        foreach( $node->childNodes as $bet ){
            echo "<div>Name: {$bet->getAttribute('name')} ID: {$bet->getAttribute('id')} Price: {$bet->getAttribute('price')}</div>";
        }
        echo '</section>';
    }
    echo "</div>";

} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}
$dom = $xp = $col = null;


outputs:

Tottenham v Leicester - [ BTTS + Match Result ]
Sun, 10 January, 2016 16:00:00
Name: Draw ID: 264032028.20 Price: 7/2
Name: Tottenham ID: 264032029.20 Price: 5/2
Name: Leicester ID: 264032030.20 Price: 15/2

Tottenham v Leicester - [ Match Result & Over 2.5 ]
Sun, 10 January, 2016 16:00:00
Name: Draw ID: 264032035.20 Price: 11/1
Name: Tottenham ID: 264032036.20 Price: 6/4
Name: Leicester ID: 264032037.20 Price: 13/2

Tottenham v Leicester - [ Match Result & Under 2.5 ]
Sun, 10 January, 2016 16:00:00
Name: Draw ID: 264032038.20 Price: 7/2
Name: Tottenham ID: 264032039.20 Price: 3/1
Name: Leicester ID: 264032040.20 Price: 17/2
```

Comment: many thanks, just added stop asking silly questions and look hard first to list of things to do in the new year :)

Comment: also one more thing, the event name is now no longer displayed

Comment: ive updated my code now however its not displaying the bet values
this is how ive formatted it

Comment: If you notice I had changed the xpath expression to target the bettype node rather than directly at the bet

Comment: sorry what i meant is the code ive edited above displays the bettype name  but not the bet name or price
this is since ive added the div structure that i need it formatting in

Comment: seems to be an issue with 
        foreach( $node->childNodes as $bet ){

its just not doing anything  inside it even echo "test"; does nothing

Comment: change the `eid` to the latest one from the xml source

Comment: im viewing it on my local site so it only displays teh current events so which ever event i select its updating the $eid

Comment: got it working fine now, just one thing 
this bit 

      $pattern = '/\/.*$/';
$pricedown = strstr($bet->getAttribute('price'),'/', false);
$urlprice = preg_replace($pattern,'',$bet->getAttribute('price'));

doesnt seem to be capturing the data after the /

Comment: and also why is it adding oc_idfo to strings in the url 

http://www.betfred.com/sport?mode=cf&oc_idfoselection=264450999.20&oc_idfomarket=&priceup=28&pricedown=1 

this is the bit that creates the url
echo "<div class=\"unit-30\">{$bet->getAttribute('name')} - {$bet->getAttribute('price')}<br/><a href=\"http://www.betfred.com/siteservices/affiliate/tracking.ashx?target=BetslipLanding&affid=31533&btag=a_38299b_0&selection=".$betid."&market=".$bettypeid."&priceup=".$urlprice."&pricedown=".$urlpriced."\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\"><img src=\"betnow.gif\" ></a><br />